# Android 8: Not call WakefulBroadcastReceiver.reciver()

Tags: android, android-notifications

Android Studio 3.2.1

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'



    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.myproject"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 423

def AAVersion = '4.5.2'

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:ormlite:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6'
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:ormlite-api:$AAVersion"

In Manifest.xml

  <receiver android:name="com.myproject.service.NotificationsDrawerReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="40">
                <action android:name="com.myproject.service.NotificationsSyncModule_SYNC_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here my receiver:

```
public class NotificationsDrawerReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private final static String TAG = NotificationsDrawerReceiver.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // success call on Android < 8.0
    }
}
```

When income push notification on **Android < 8.0** the method `NotificationsDrawerReceiver.onReceive()` success call. And as result success show message on Notification Drawer.

But on **Android 8.0+** method `NotificationsDrawerReceiver.onReceive()` not call. And as result not show push notification on Notification Drawer.

Comment: Create and Manage Notification Channels for notification from Oreo is Must . See this link https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 2):

Most implicit broadcasts [were banned in Android 8.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts).

If the sender of the broadcast and the receiver are in the same app and same process:

- Get rid of the `<receiver>`
- Use `LocalBroadcastManager`

If the sender of the broadcast and the receiver are in different processes of the same app:

- Get rid of the `<intent-filter>` in the `<receiver>` (which opens up security holes)
- Use an explicit `Intent` (e.g., `new Intent(this, NotificationsDrawerReceiver.class)`)

If the sender of the broadcast and the receiver are in different apps, work out an IPC option that does not involve sending an implicit broadcast.

Also note that `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` was deprecated a couple of years ago.

Comment: Broadcast is sent by external web application from remote server. Do you have some example how I must correct register my 
 NotificationsDrawerReceiver ?

Comment: @Alexei: "Broadcast is sent by external web application from remote server" -- I do not know what you mean by that. A server cannot send an arbitrary Android broadcast.

Comment: Push notifications is sent by external application (not on device). This application use cloud id to sent many notifications for all Android devices.

Comment: @Alexei: AFAIK, the "push notifications" are not directly sending a `com.myproject.service.NotificationsSyncModule_SYNC_ACTION` broadcast. Instead, some code of yours is doing that, perhaps in response to an FCM message. Find your code that is sending this broadcast, then follow the instructions in my answer.